# Is there any way to remove gerrit code review +1 which was given by mistake? can we remove with any command or something?

Tags: gerrit

I have given code review +1 instead of giving verified +1 on Gerrit.. now i need to remove +1 which I gave.. Is that possible?

I tried checking the docs but couldn't find anything relevant related to removing the already given code review.. now I don't want to abandon the commit and push it freshly as i have to do few tasks for the new commit which consumes lot of time and effort.

Comment: Don't spam unrelated tags.